# Set data as true or false based on xml node value

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data that looks similar to the xml at the very bottom of this question. This is 3 of thousands of tasks. Some have `<DayOfWeek>` nodes, some don't. I am working on taking this data and putting it into a csv so that it can be imported into sql.

My goal is to have each day be a column in the table and each row represent a task. If it is scheduled to run on a given day a 1 will be in the respective day, otherwise it will be a 0. For the below data at the bottom of this question, the table would look like this

```
| taskID | mon | tue | wed | thur | fri | sat | sun |
|________|_____|_____|_____|______|_____|_____|_____|
|    1   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1   |  1  |  1  |  0  |
|    2   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0   |  1  |  0  |  0  |
|    3   |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1   |  1  |  1  |  1  |
```

My current ps script makes this data more vertical as opposed to horizontal. An excerpt from the code

```
foreach($task in $config.Settings.Tasks.Task){
    $taskID = $task.ID
    foreach($DoW in $task.Schedules.Schedule.Days.DayOfWeek){
        $newCSV += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'taskID' = $taskID; 'Day' = $DoW})
    }
}
$newCSV | Export-Csv -Path c:\users\mhopkins\desktop\micSchedule\DoW.csv -notype
```

Can you guys help make this data work a little better in a table for me?

XML snippit

```
<Task ID="1" Name="name1" Active="1" NextEID="11">
    <Schedules>
        <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="0">
            <Days>
                <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
            </Days>
        </Schedule>
    </Schedules>
</Task>
<Task ID="2" Name="name2" Active="1" NextEID="12">
    <Schedules>
        <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="0">
            <Days>
                <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
            </Days>
        </Schedule>
    </Schedules>
</Task>
<Task ID="3" Name="name3" Active="0" NextEID="24" TT="COS" AR="0">
    <Schedules>
        <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="1">
            <Days>
                <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
                <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
            </Days>
        </Schedule>
    </Schedules>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add to lines to your XML snipit to get it to work for PowerShell.

```
<xml>
...
</xml>
```

I was using PowerShell v 3.0 and got this to work.

```
$config = [xml](get-content 'dat.xml')

foreach($task in $config.xml.Task){

    $props = @{
        'taskID'=$task.ID
        'Sunday'=$NULL
        'Monday'=$NULL
        'Tuesday'=$NULL
        'Wednesday'=$NULL
        'Thursday'=$NULL
        'Friday'=$NULL
        'Saturday'=$NULL
    }

    foreach($DoW in $task.Schedules.Schedule.Days.DayOfWeek){
        foreach($day in $DoW){
            #POWERSHELL!!!
            $props.$day = $true #Or equals 1 whatever  
        }   
    }

    $newCSV += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props)
}
$newCSV
```

This is the output that I got.

```
Thursday  : True
Sunday    :
taskID    : 1
Saturday  : True
Friday    : True
Tuesday   :
Monday    : True
Wednesday :

Thursday  :
Sunday    :
taskID    : 2
Saturday  :
Friday    : True
Tuesday   :
Monday    : True
Wednesday :

Thursday  : True
Sunday    : True
taskID    : 3
Saturday  : True
Friday    : True
Tuesday   : True
Monday    : True
Wednesday : True
```

PowerShell outputs it strange but it's all organized. You can always use format table `$newCSV | Format-Table TaskID,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday -AutoSize`. Export-CSV will keep all the columns correct.

**UPDATE**

You can always use a [`switch` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) to edit the properties. Swap out `$props.$day = $true` for a good'ole switch statement like this:

```
foreach($DoW in $task.Schedules.Schedule.Days.DayOfWeek){
    foreach($day in $DoW){
        #$props.$day = $true
        switch ($day){
            'Sunday'{$props.Sunday = $true}
            'Monday'{$props.Monday = $true}
            'Tuesday'{$props.Tuesday = $true}
            'Wednesday'{$props.Wednesday = $true}
            'Thursday'{$props.Thursday = $true}
            'Friday'{$props.Friday = $true}
            'Saturday'{$props.Saturday = $true}
            default{"$day is not a Day of the Week"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm 90% sure this is user error on my part. I'm getting the error `Property '' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.` In reference to the `$props.$day = $true`

Comment: Could this be because some tasks don't have `Schedule.Days.DayOfWeek`?

Comment: Using the switch statement gives you a little more flexibility. You can change the names of the properties from `Sunday to sun, Monday to mon,...`

Answer (score 0):

Convential wisdom seems to be that you should cast it as [XML], but if there are thousands of them I suspect that's going to get pretty heavy-handed on the CPU and memory.  Maybe somebody else will post that solution for comparison.

In the meantime:

```
[regex]$regex = @'
(?ms)\s*<Task ID="(\d+)".+?
\s*<Days>(.+?)
\s*</Days>.+?
\s*</Task>
'@

$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\tasks.xml')
&{
$regex.Matches($text) |
foreach {
 $Schedule = 
 new-object psobject -Property @{
                                 taskID = $_.groups[1].value
                                 mon    = 0
                                 tue    = 0
                                 wed    = 0
                                 thur   = 0
                                 fri    = 0
                                 sat    = 0
                                 sun    = 0
                                 }
    switch -Regex ($_.groups[2].value)
    {
     'Monday'    {$Schedule.mon  = 1}
     'Tuesday'   {$Schedule.tue  = 1}
     'Wednesday' {$Schedule.wed  = 1}
     'Thursday'  {$Schedule.thur = 1}
     'Friday'    {$Schedule.fri  = 1}
     'Saturday'  {$Schedule.sat  = 1}
     'Sunday'    {$Schedule.sun  = 1}
     }
   $schedule 
  }
}| select taskID,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun | ft -auto

taskID mon tue wed thur fri sat sun
------ --- --- --- ---- --- --- ---
1        1   0   0    1   1   1   0
2        1   0   0    0   1   0   0
3        1   1   1    1   1   1   1
```